# How to stop getting error and keep data: Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x31 found at location 116

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, razorsql

I'm trying to copy data from Amazon s3 into Amazon Redshift but I keep getting the "Unexpected character" newline error at the same line every time. Its a random line in the middle of the file and this has been happening to a lot of my files that I'm trying to copy over.

Here is the copy statement:

```
COPY sample_table FROM "S3://bucket/file.psv' iam_role 'role' delimiter '|'
ACCEPTINVCHARS IGNOREBLANKLINES DATEFORMAT 'auto' TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
emptyasnull blanksasnull maxerror as 100000 ;
```

Here is the table format:

```
create table sample_table (
id varchar (25),
model varchar (25),
api varchar (25),
msgdatetime timestamp,
msgdate date,
alias bigint,
key varchar (255),
value varchar (50)
) ;
```

Here is the raw line from the data:

```
AAA111111111|AA1111111|sample_API|2019-06-06 11:20:00|2019-06-06|111111111|Sample_key|1
```

It should also be noted that this is part of an automated process where the sql above is used to copy numerous files that are all causing the same problem.

Comment: does this example work? i mean if you have a s3 with that 1 row does it fail with that copy command? please check and if not you need to update your example.

Comment: @JonScott It works because it copies over the rest of the data from the same file but skips over this line and spits out an error and all the other rows are formatted the same

Comment: If i create an s3 with this one line, then run the create table and the copy command - it works just fine, that 1 row is properly loaded in to the table. In order to get help make sure you can get a verifiable example that actually fails. Also - you may wish to update your title as that's not the error is it?

Comment: @JonScott that is indeed the exact error that I get and this s3 file is a file pulled from another source, not created directly in s3. It's also worth mentioning that the file is a psv.

Comment: psv is what exactly? just a text file? In your text you have a different message than your header. (maybe?). please can you provide more rows? there is no way i can help you with what you have provided as - as i said above - it works! you need to help me recreate it - try recreating it yourself using the info you have provided?

Comment: @JonScott what does the "0x31" and "location 116" mean?

Comment: "0x31" is the "1" character - see https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=0x

Comment: The error message seems odd because you don't have 116 characters in the line. Check the previous line and see whether you notice any new line characters where it shouldn't be present.

Answer (score 0):

you have more columns in your data than you have in your table

```
id = AAA111111111
model = AA1111111
api = sample_API
msgdatetime = 2019-06-06 11:20:00
msgdate  = 2019-06-06
key = 111111111
value = Sample_key
```

which leaves "1" at the end as the next column. 1 is 0x31

You probably need a new column (that I have called newcol below)

```
create table sample_table (
id varchar (25),
model varchar (25),
api varchar (25),
msgdatetime timestamp,
msgdate date,
newcol varchar(255),
key varchar (255),
value varchar (50)
) ;
```

Comment: I copied that over incorrectly. I already have an extra column (see edited post)